# If condition uses old state in the functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am building a create functionality working with react and laravel and I've encountered an error I am unable to fix. The thing is, I am catching an error and trying to process it in a nice way, if the error isn't shown then make the "success operations".

Some code:

```
const createProduct = async (event) => {
    const RESPONSE = await axios.post('/api/create-product', formData, {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    })
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
        const errorValues = Object.values(error.response.data.errors);
        const errorsArray = [];

        errorValues.forEach((errorArray) => {
            // Save message from API to an array and omit the dot
            errorArray.forEach((errorMessage) => errorsArray.push(errorMessage.slice(0, errorMessage.length - 1)));
        })

        setMessage({
            show: true,
            text: errorsArray.join(', '),
            type: 'danger',
        });
    });
    if( message.show == false ) {
        if( RESPONSE.status ) {
             do things ...
        }
    }
}
```

but react compares the old state in case the error has been encountered and then throws an error "Can't access property status, RESPONSE is undefined" ... Any suggestions on how to bypass this behavior?

EDIT: Resolved it by adding try and catch block.
Code:

```
try {
        const RESPONSE = await axios.post('/api/create-product', formData, {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        })
        .then((response) => response.data);

        if( RESPONSE.status ) {
            do things...
        }

        if( RESPONSE.message ) {
            setMessage({
                show: true,
                text: RESPONSE.message,
                type: RESPONSE.status ? 'success' : 'danger',
            });
        }
    } catch(error) {
        const errorValues = Object.values(error.response.data.errors);
        const errorsArray = [];

        errorValues.forEach((errorArray) => {
            // Save message from the API to an array and omit the dot
            errorArray.forEach((errorMessage) => errorsArray.push(errorMessage.slice(0, errorMessage.length - 1)));
        })

        setMessage({
            show: true,
            text: errorsArray.join(', '),
            type: 'danger',
        });

        return Promise.reject(errorsArray);
    }
```

Comment: Since you are not returing anything from catch the resultant `RESPONSE` will be `undefined`.

You can resolve it by adding `return Promise.resolve(someData)` in `.catch`

Comment: thank you! I forgot I have to return something in the method, but your advice didn't help, I resolved an issue, check the edited post.